# http request inside a service constructor

Tags: angular

In my application I have an Angular Service

```
export class SelectionStatusService{
      constructor(private http: HttpClient,) {
          this.loadFromLocalStorage();
      
          this.http.post<{
            ordineCorrente: OrdineCorrente,
            ordineCampagna: OrdineCampagna
          }>(`${environment.baseUrlApi}/contesti/selectContesto`, this.selection)
            .subscribe(x=> {

              ...

            })    
      
      }

      ...
}
```

If I reload my page it seams that HttpClient is not yet ready when  invoked and I get error message

HTTP_INTERCEPTORS. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200

I registered an HTTP interceptor in my application. If I do the same call later when Angular has initialized all its component all is working.
In there a special way to make an http request inside  a service constructor?

Comment: How are you creating your service ?

Comment: The costructor depend only on HttpClient BUT I have also an HttpInterceptor that depend on an AuthService for the local storage that in turn depended on the original SelectionStatusService creating a circular injection. Apparently Angular do not check and works fine as long as you do not use HttpClient in the constructor.  I figure out how to break the circular dependency and now it's fine

Comment: is the reported issue resolved after you remnoved the cisrcular dependency?

Comment: yes, now the application works